# Determining Big O for a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, big-o

I am trying to figure out how to determine Big O notation for recursive methods . I realise that is probably the same way as with a iterative method, but im not sure about this.

I wrote this simple recursive Java program:

```
public RecursiveFunctions() {
recursiveFunction1(2);
}

// Meget simpel rekursiv metode der taeller en Integer ned 
public void recursiveFunction1(int someInteger) {
    System.out.println("Tallet er nu : " + someInteger);
    someInteger = someInteger * 2;
    if (someInteger < 100) {
        recursiveFunction1(someInteger);            
    }
}
```

I am not sure of this, but my guess would be that this is a O(n) or a O(1) notation?
Also, what would a O(n^2) or O(log(n)) contain?

Comment: you can increment a global variable say countRecursive1 in that function ? what are you trying to do ?? if you want to calculate it use other theorems to do so [Masters theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) is a good choice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how you look at this, it's either O(1) because it will always take at most 7 iterations for positive inputs, you could say it will be O(lg n) because the number of iterations required will change relative to the lg base 2 of the input, or that it is undefined because the computation never completes for non-positive inputs. Take your pick!

Comment: Strictly speaking, O-notation has sense only when some parameter tends to infinity, it's not about the "proportionality on the way". So the only correct answer is O(1).

Comment: I disagree on that it must tend toward infinity to be useful; I agree that infinity is the most common thing to... 'tend toward'?

Comment: it's not about usefulness, just O() is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) in such a way.

Comment: Vlad, if you read your link (the third equation in the section linked) you find it clearly stating that you can tend toward another number `a` (in this case, 0) and still be within the formal definition.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But the given function is exactly O(1) as `someInteger` tends to infinity, right? Which variable should tend to which limit in order to justify `O(log n)`?

Answer (score 1):

You must determine the cost (Function C(n)) of the base case/s, and the cost of the recursive call. For example, for the factorial function:

```
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    if(n < 2) //This is O(1), so not affect to the result (We could think as its a constant 'a')
        return 1; //As the comparison, think its a constant 'b', so C(0) and C(1) = b + a;
    else
        return n * factorial(n-1); //The multiplication (O(1), a constant 'c') and the call C(n-1), so C(n) = c + a + C(n-1)
}
```

Now, expand the function C(n) for a set of values, to find a progression:

```
C(0) = a + b
C(1) = a + b
C(2) = (c+a) + C(1) = (c+a) + a + b
C(3) = (c+a) + C(2) = (c+a) + (c+a) + C(1) = (c+a) + (c+a) + a + b
C(4) = (c+a) + C(3) = (c+a) + (c+a) + C(2) = (c+a) + (c+a) + (c+a) + C(1) = (c+a) + (c+a) + c + a + b
C(5) = (c+a) + C(4) = (c+a) + (c+a) + C(3) = (c+a) + (c+a) + (c+a) + C(2) = (c+a)  + (c+a) + (c+a) + (c+a) + C(1) = (c+a) + (c+a) + (c+a) + (c+a) + a + b
...
C(n) = (n-1)*(c+a) + a + b --> O(n)
```

But think that big O only has meaning with big n, not little numbers, as in your code (Your code does at least seven calls, wich is equivalent to O(1)).

Answer (score 0):

In general, finding asymptotic growth for recurrence methods can be quite complex, but this task can often be solved using [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Your example is too simple. It can be easily transformed into iterative function with almost equivalent performance. Then you can find Big-O of iterative method (looks like you know how to do it).